# Updating two repositories from a single local project based on folders

Tags: git, repository, push, boilerplate

I have 2 repositories:

**Master** and **Slave**

**Master** is simply a boilerplate inside which there is a "**CORE**" folder with some source files.

**Slave** is a satellite project, it is born by cloning the **Master** boilerplate and then proceeds in development separately.

If during development on the **Slave** repository a file inside the "**CORE**" folder is changed, I would like to be able to push the change to the **Master** repository as well.

This is because when we eventually have to start a **NewSlave** project by cloning from the **Master** boilerplate I would like to have all the changes to the **CORE** made in the **Slave** projects

The approach I am trying is to add a second remote to all "**Slave**" projects pointing to the **Master** boilerplate repository, commit the changes to the "**CORE**" folder separately and push them to **Master**
Unfortunately, that's an approach that doesn't work unless you force/rebase every time.

Ps: Due to the structure of the project, it is impossible to use submodules.

Any suggestions will be welcome